# I try different forms to load data (csv file in my computer) in PySpark but the error is the same

Tags: pyspark, google-colaboratory

The code of the first picture is to install PySpark and initiate Spark session.

In second picture is to load csv file and the error.

[image: start]

[image: error]

Comment: If you're using google colab, you need to upload the csv file from your computer to the colab environment first. Colab cannot read files directly from your computer.

Comment: Thanks. I followed the instructions on this site https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-importando-csv-no-google-colab-86862, it's just a matter of indicating the correct path where the file is.